# Jenkins thinBackup plugin is not working

Tags: jenkins, plugins, backup

I am using Jenkins `v1.651.3` and to schedule automated daily backup I have installed the [ThinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) plugin `v1.9`. But when I trigger backup manually it does not work. In the system logs all I can see is -

```
Sep 01, 2017 9:31:37 AM INFO org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.thinbackup.ThinBackupMgmtLink doBackupManual
Starting manual backup.
```

Comment: Does your `jenkins user` have write permission to the directory where you are trying to create the backup?

Comment: Yes, it has. Otherwise it would have thrown some error in logs, isn't?

Comment: Sometimes, it doesn't. I had that problem and it was because of permission issue.

Comment: OK thanks for the pointer I will check, you can add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the backup process doesn't take place because of the directory permission issue.

Make sure that your `Jenkins` user has the write permission to the directory where you are trying to create your backup.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue like this, and in my case was as simple as the Backup directory was not correctly set or empty. If this settings of the ThinBackup is not set, when you launch it manually it does nothing, and no error at all is shown. After set a correct path, it works normally. Then my advise is to check your settings to see if something is wrong.

Comment: Checking the jenkins.err.log led me to the same path fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @ANIL his answer saves my day.

Previously I backup Jenkins to a mount folder, but it doesn't work recently. so I use user
`jenkins` to log in on the Jenkins server then try the below commands

`cd $BACKUP_FOLDER`

`bash: cd: data: Stale file handle`

My `jenkins` user can't access this directory, but I personal user can. But anyway, this problem is caused by permission.